# GIT - lost everything after being accidentally in detached HEAD and making a wrong commit?

Tags: git

I dont remember what I did but all my work from months is gone.
For long time I was committing files to git. I must have misspelled the commit command, I dont remember (and cannot see it anymore). Then the following happend:

I was in detached HEAD

I might have stashed files

I checked out to main branch
I found my commit but in this branch and last commit almost everything is gone.

In my history in detached head

```
commit 2be5fe718cf6ed42250b7b190573b04300697b50 (HEAD, main)
Reflog: HEAD@{0} (...)
Reflog message: checkout: moving from main to 2be5fe718cf6ed42250b7b190573b04300697b50
Author: ...
Date:   Sat Jan 14 18:14:59 2023 +0100

     change getcloseststation to first select a line

commit 2be5fe718cf6ed42250b7b190573b04300697b50 (HEAD, main)
Reflog: HEAD@{1} (...)
Reflog message: commit: change getcloseststation to first select a line
Author: ...
Date:   Sat Jan 14 18:14:59 2023 +0100

     change getcloseststation to first select a line

commit a2f2d7c0f126e954606249bfc728cc930841dce1 (origin/main)
Reflog: HEAD@{2} (...)
Reflog message: checkout: moving from 804021e233b9edcbb68e08dae1a901d6fb23d3cc to main
Author: ...
Date:   Sat Sep 17 16:57:40 2022 +0200
```

I tried to go there and do  git stash pop (since I think I stashed it) but nothing there to be stashed.
I only have 2 branches which is main and detached HEAD.

Also in both detached HEAD and main, I can only see my last commit and another comment 4 months ago. All my other commits disappeared - BOTH in detached HEAD and main..
Im afraid to do anything more wrong and fully loose everything. I know its not fully clear what happened, but its all I know. I would appreciate help so much as its soo much Ive lost..Thanks a lot!!!

when running git log 2be5fe718 or gitk 2be5fe718 on copied repo, I only get the following (1 commit from4 months ago and my last commit that I did today but where everything is gone

```
commit 2be5fe718cf6ed42250b7b190573b04300697b50 (HEAD -> main)
Author: ...>
Date:   Sat Jan 14 18:14:59 2023 +0100

     change getcloseststation to first select a line

commit a2f2d7c0f126e954606249bfc728cc930841dce1 (origin/main)
Author: ...>
Date:   Sat Sep 17 16:57:40 2022 +0200

    checkout
```

EDIT:

```
2be5fe71 (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{9}: commit: change getcloseststation to first select a line
a2f2d7c0 (origin/main) HEAD@{10}: checkout: moving from 804021e233b9edcbb68e08dae1a901d6fb23d3cc to main
804021e2 HEAD@{11}: commit: change getcloseststation to first select a line
```

Comment: Can you post the result for `git branch --all`?

Comment: when Im in main i get this:  main
  remotes/origin/main

Comment: Relax, breathe. Create a backup of your working tree, including the `.git` repository. If you do `git log 2be5fe718` or `gitk 2be5fe718`, your commits are not there?

Comment: could you please tell me how to do a backup of my working tree?

Comment: You copy your directory with all its content to a new location. Or you create a tar file from it. Whatever works.

Comment: so I git cloned it. when I run those commands nothing is there still. only my last commit (however everything is missing there) and a commit 4 months ago

Comment: Don't clone, clone will only take commits reachable through refs (which you don't have, since you were committing with detached HEAD). Create a real copy, using your OS' functions (`cp -a` or use a file browser). Creating a backup (copy) is done to prevent doing further accidental damage.

Comment: Can you tell me which OS' functions I need to use for this? I mean, you dont mean to just copy paste my repo?!

Comment: @juliascoding That's exactly what I mean. What did you think that "make a backup" means? Create a backup, so that in case something goes wrong during recovery, you can start again from the start.

Comment: Nevertheless, did the log/gitk commands not work, i.e. not show your commits?

Comment: those commands didnt show my commits

Comment: I edited my question to show what I get in my terminal

Comment: @juliascoding Are you sure you are in the correct directory? Because if you committed, those commits must show up in `git reflog` (this is a _different_ command from `git log`). You show some output which contains reflog references, so I assumed you already ran it. Just double-checking, because the output looks a bit strange.

Comment: oh I didnt know. Ok git reflog does show my commits (not sure if my last commit that lost my stuff still has lost it) but at least my previous commits are shown here. I edit my question to show the pre last commit and my last commit (that should have my changes but lost everything from 4 month)

Comment: so 2be5fe71 (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{9}: is for my ast commit

Comment: @juliascoding `804021e233b9edcbb68e08dae1a901d6fb23d3cc` likely was your detached HEAD. `gitk 804021e` should show your "lost" commits.

Comment: oh wow thank you so much for helping me!! I was so stressed I lost everything!

Comment: no so I dont make any mistakes: im in detached HEAD now, how do I commit my changes of where I am now and leave detached HEAD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a backup of your directory in case your screw up.
2. Use `git reflog` to find the lost commit(s). You can use `git log $commit_hash` or `gitk $commit_hash` to verify.
3. Once you have the commit hash, create a new branch to point to that commit: `git branch $commit_hash_from_reflog`
4. Check out or push this new branch
5. Don't forget to be happy